# Как запустить и остановить процесс (запуска node) в утилите daemon-tools

Tags: node.js, веб-сервер

Как запустить и остановить процесс (запуска node) в утилите daemon-tools ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если daemontools уже установлены (т.е. в системе присутствует директория /etc/service), то внутри неё нужно создать директорию для Node.js с любым именем и положить туда скрипт, который будет его запускать. Этот файл обязательно должен называться "run". Как только супервайзер его увидит (а он постоянно следит за всеми директориями в /etc/service), он сразу же его запустит. Предположим, что поддиректория со скриптом будет называться nodejs. Тогда команды для запуска и остановки будут следующими:

```
sudo svc -u /etc/service/nodejs (запуск)
sudo svc -d /etc/service/nodejs (остановка)
```

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд проще и лучше всего подымать Node.js демона путем использования модуля **[forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)**.

Тем не менее, если так принципиально использовать именно daemon-tools, всю необходимую информацию можно найти [здесь](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html).

###### Но, справедливости ради - достаточно лишь взглянуть на количество форков на gihub'e что-бы понять уровень одного и другого решения.

---

Quick guide:

```
sudo npm install -g forever      # установка

forever start script.js          # запуск
forever stop script.js           # остановка   
forever restart script.js        # перезапуск
# etc...
```

Comment: раньше не мог написать))

Comment: @Zow - очевидно-же, что не мог.

Comment: @AlexWindHope а можно это установить и не удалять daemon&

Comment: Отчего-же нельзя? Конечно-же можно. Использование необходимого тебе, на данный момент, функционала и установку я описал, благо это элементарно.

Но вот только какой тогда смысл daemon-tools?